# Scala Lift - Mongodb update multiple records

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift

I have the following

```
Document.update(

    ("room" -> "test") ~ ("module" -> "item"), 
    ("$set" -> 

        ("active" -> 0)

    )

 )
```

However only one item is updated, how do I update all records that match?

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default mongo only updates the first row it finds, to make it update multiple matching rows you need to pass the "multi" update option. In scala I believe it would look something like this:

`Document.update(
    ("room" -> "test") ~ ("module" -> "item"), 
    ("$set" -> ("active" -> 0)),
    Multi
)`